# Bootstrap/css nof found/working on IE and ED

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

I am working on a web application, to my "big surprise" I found that my css / bootstrap on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge is not working. I have already tried several things that are on stackoverflow but nothing works, someone happens to see the problem

[Console EDGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0pr5.png)

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta informatie -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../assets/img/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/img/favicon.png">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    
    
    <!-- Titel -->
    <title>Login</title>
    
    <!-- CSS files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="assets/css/stylesIndex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    
</head>
```

Regards

Bart Balloon

Comment: can you show the error console ?

Comment: @B.S. Check image in post =D

Comment: @Bartballon Stack Overflow doesn’t have ‘karma’ like Reddit. It’s called reputation (or just ‘rep’)

Comment: jha, I couldn't get the word out, was in a hurry XD, in the end it all ends up in the Same anyway = D, but will remember!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have problem with the code, your problem is with your IE that you are using in my opinion.
I tested your site on IE 11 and it's look fine, as following picture.
[image: IE11]